# How to return std::vector<std::pair<std::string, int> > from java to c++ using swig typemaps

Tags: java, c++, vector, java-native-interface, swig

I am trying to send some data from java code to c++ code in the form of

```
std::vector<std::pair<std::string, int> >
```

using SWIG. I use the following .i file:

```
%module example{

%include <std_pair.i>
%include <std_vector.i>
%include <std_string.i>

%template(Pair) std::pair<std::string , int>;
%template(VectorPair) std::vector<std::pair<std::string , int> >;

%}
```

In java I do

```
VectorPair v = new VectorPair();
for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++){
         Pair temp = new Pair("some_string",j);
         v.add(temp);
      }

 v.delete();
```

And in c++ I receive like this:

```
void func(std::vector<std::pair<std::string , int> > A){
     //do something ....
     }
```

It works fine, but turns out that whenever I make a Pair or VectorPair in Java, I make a duplicate in c++ and I cannot delete them. So when I repeat this in a loop, I run out of memory. Would you please help me delete these duplicates or use a typemap to do this?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what does `delete` do in your Java code ? There is no manual memory management in Java, so I'm interested. Is it a method written using JNI ?

Comment: I am using SWIG. If a pointer is created such as 

     SWIGTYPE_p_double A = example.new_jarray_double(n)

Then you have to delete it later ... 

But in this case it doesn't work. it does nothing ...

Comment: What is the code of `VectorPair.delete` ?

Comment: I assumed that it would be generated automatically by SWIG since that's the case for pointer types. And it gives no errors!

Comment: If you want to understand what's going on you need a deeper understanding of what's happening, not hoping the technology you are using works like you *think* is working. I do know anything about SWIG so right now it's up to you to dive in their doc

Comment: If you wouldn't mind using another tool, there's a couple of examples for JavaCPP in this file: https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp-presets/blob/master/opencv/src/main/java/org/bytedeco/javacpp/presets/opencv_core.java

Answer (score 1):

Java should just garbage collect the `VectorPair` when it's done with, so all you need to do is say:

```
v = null;
```

to make sure that you don't retain any references to it inside your Java code.

The tricky thing is that Java won't be aware of the true memory used by this object because it doesn't see how much allocation happens inside C++ by default. This means that the objects won't get garbage collected even when there is memory pressure on your application because the JVM simply doesn't know that there is this pressure.

What you want to do therefore is make sure that Java is used to do *all* allocations in your C++ code, not just the Java specific ones. There's [detailed instructions on using the JVM's heap](http://www.swig.org/Doc2.0/Java.html#Java_heap_allocations) in the SWIG documentation. The short version of it is that you're going to write `operator new` (and of course a corresponding `operator delete`) to allocate memory on the JVM's heap.

As a general point it seems odd that you're passing your vector by value here. Passing by const reference seems to be more appropriate for avoiding excessive copying/allocations.